# Why ! operator returns true for different expressions?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following javascript

```
var test = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

In the console, type

```
test.indexOf('1') > -1;
```

Result will be true.

Now add the basic Not operator !.

```
!test.indexOf('1') > -1;
```

Result is also true, but I expected the result to be false. Why is it true?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is because `!` has higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `>`, so first, the result of `test.indexOf()` is negated, in your example that results in 0 being negated, so it becomes `true`. This is then used in the context of inequality, which converts `true` to `1` for the comparison. As `1 > -1` you get a result of `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You got `true` because you negated the **left-hand value**

```
 !test.indexOf('1')
```

not the **whole expression**

```
 !(test.indexOf('1') > -1).
```

In other words :

```
!test.indexOf('1') > -1  // expected true
```

**Is not the same as**

```
!(test.indexOf('1') > -1) // expected false
```

Like Math statements :

```
5*2+2 // not the same as 5*(2+2)
```